# simple node api request don't display any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Look I have request in my server.js file

```
var Post = require('./../models/post');
//GET ALL POSTS
app.get('/api/posts', function (req, res) {
    Post.getPosts(function (err, posts) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

and my post.js model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: { type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

// Get All Posts
module.exports.getPosts = function (callback, limit) {
    Post.find(callback).limit(limit);
};
```

In my eye all code is written right but it does not display data so I double check the mongoDB if i have any record there:

```
> show dbs
admin      0.000GB
bookstore  0.000GB
local      0.000GB
ownfb      0.000GB
> use ownfb
switched to db ownfb
> show collections
posts
> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597aa5b04c08c647b4efb58d"), "type" : "user", "body" : "POST_Z_MONGOOSE_YO" }
```

MongoDB looks good and contains one record so why when I go to url *http://localhost:5000/api/posts*

It shows nothing except empty array

> []

Also I do not get any error in cmd/browser.

Gist full code of those 2 files:

server.js: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b04527e97e889dcaa109f3ff459a5da

post.js: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e77064ae71b5ef6d5a9abfd897187ddf

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in the correct parameters into your getPosts() function. It's expecting callback and limit... I bet it's using 0 as the limit since you're not giving it any.

OR

You could try only having one export. postSchema.getPosts() is where you could attach the method and then just export mongoose.model('Post', postSchema); and nothing else.

Comment: Well, `limit` will be `undefined`. But I don't know what Mongoose does when you call `.limit(undefined)`. Maybe it counts that as 0?

Comment: I'm not sure what Mongo would do. Only other thing I see wrong is the module.exports syntax. I have never seen it done that way.

Answer (score 0):

`app.get('/api/posts', function (req, res) {
        Post.getPosts(function (err, posts) {
           res.json(posts);
           res.end();  // !!!!!
        });
    // returns here with no results
    });`

Please note the `res.end()` function that must be called after `res.json()` to actually transfer the data.

Comment: So how my code should looks like? I can not hendle that i understand what you write but how can i change it and fix it?

Comment: Just add `res.end()` after `res.json(posts)` line